# How to find total possibilities of 4 events?

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, variance

Say you had 4 coins being tossed simultaneously, and a total score (X) is given by 3 points for each head and 1 point for each tail, added together.  How would you find the total possibilities and the the probably of getting 8 for example?

This is easy enough if it is 2 coins, but going through each event individually is tedious with 4 coins.

Comment: Unfortunately you may need to go through each possible outcome. However, making a chart of possible outcomes should help. Each coin toss has 2 possible outcomes, and there are 4 coin tosses, so a table of $2^4=16$ rows can list all the outcomes. Although somewhat tedious, it wouldn't be unreasonable to fill out by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, split it into **disjoint** events of **equal** probability:

```
 C 1 | C 2 | C 3 | C 4 | Score
-----|-----|-----|-------------
  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |   4
  1  |  1  |  1  |  3  |   6
  1  |  1  |  3  |  1  |   6
  1  |  1  |  3  |  3  |   8
  1  |  3  |  1  |  1  |   6
  1  |  3  |  1  |  3  |   8
  1  |  3  |  3  |  1  |   8
  1  |  3  |  3  |  3  |  10
  3  |  1  |  1  |  1  |   6
  3  |  1  |  1  |  3  |   8
  3  |  1  |  3  |  1  |   8
  3  |  1  |  3  |  3  |  10
  3  |  3  |  1  |  1  |   8
  3  |  3  |  1  |  3  |  10
  3  |  3  |  3  |  1  |  10
  3  |  3  |  3  |  3  |  12
```

Then, count the number of combinations of the specific score that you're interested in:

- The number of combinations that sum up to $ 4$ is $1$
- The number of combinations that sum up to $ 6$ is $4$
- The number of combinations that sum up to $ 8$ is $6$
- The number of combinations that sum up to $10$ is $4$
- The number of combinations that sum up to $12$ is $1$

Finally, divide this number by the total number of combinations, which happens to be $16$:

- $P(\text{score}= 4)=\frac{1}{16}$
- $P(\text{score}= 6)=\frac{4}{16}$
- $P(\text{score}= 8)=\frac{6}{16}$
- $P(\text{score}=10)=\frac{4}{16}$
- $P(\text{score}=12)=\frac{1}{16}$